# Automatically import google forms quiz results to google classroom

Tags: google-forms, google-classroom

When students in google classroom submit my google forms, they are automatically graded and students can see their results. Despite that when I want to import these quiz results into my google classroom, I need to do it manually with import grades button. **Is there a way to automate this process?** That means that when student submits the form, the results will be immediately visible in his google classroom.

Please do not tell me to change LMS, google classroom is a requirement for me.

Answer (score 0):

### There's no need to use Forms outside Classroom, you can integrate it

As a teacher go to your **Class > Classwork** and click on **Create > Quiz assignment**, fill the needed data like **Title, Instructions, Students, Points, etc**. Then click on the **Form** and edit it as required.

When you are done editing, save it and close the Form, then on the Classroom side click on **Assign**. Once you assigned the quiz to the students, this automatically will be reflected on the student classwork and this student can access your quiz trough the Classroom Platform.

### If you want to export this data to another service then use Google Apps Script in order to automate your process

***You can skip this if it's not necessary***

As an approach to export this data using Apps Script, open the **Form** and open the **Script Editor** then copy this code:

```
function myFunction() {

  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.setCollectEmail(true);
  var responses = form.getResponses();
  responses.forEach(response => {
    let email = response.getRespondentEmail();
    let score = 0;
    response.getGradableItemResponses().forEach(item => {
      score += Number.parseFloat(item.getScore());
    });
    
    // Handle your submit and export this data to an extra service
  });
  
}
```

Then you can handle the submit event by creating a [onSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1) trigger in your Apps Script project.

### Reference

[Class FormApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app)

[FormApp.getActiveForm()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#getactiveform)

[Class Form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form)

[Form.setCollectEmail(collect)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setcollectemailcollect)

[Form.getResponses()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getresponses)

[Class FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)

[FormResponse.getRespondentEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getrespondentemail)

[FormResponse.getGradableItemResponses()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getgradableitemresponses)

[Class ItemResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response)

[ItemResponse.getScore()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#getscore)

Answer (score 0):

**What you want cannot be achieved for now.**

The reason for this is essentially because before importing the grades, the teacher can modify/change the already existing grades if needed before sending them to the students.

What you can do in this situation is to file a **Feature Request** on Google Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191645&template=823908) and provide all the necessary details.